# Launching media (video) on the Echo Show?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've been tasked with developing a skill for the Amazon Echo Show. I've used templates from the Alexa Github repository, but they haven't been updated for the Show.

Essentially what I need help with is finding how to load a video following a prompt. I found this bit of code:

```
"version": "1.1",
"sessionAttributes": {},
"response": {
    "reprompt": {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "text": "Hello? Are you still there?"
        }
    },
    "outputSpeech": null,
    "card": null,
    "directives": [
        {
            "type": "VideoApp.Launch",
            "videoItem": {
                "source": "[url to video.mp4]",
                "metadata": {
                    "title": "Title meta",
                    "subtitle": "Secondary Title for Sample Video"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

but I'm not sure how the intent schema works with this or how it works within the context of existing code for a prompt. Sorry this is so long winded but I'm at a loss, any input would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to start a video:

```
const videoSource = 'https://url/myvideo.mp4';
const metadata = {
        'title': 'Title for Sample Video',
        'subtitle': 'Secondary Title for Sample Video'
    };
this.response.playVideo(videoSource, metadata);
this.emit(':responseReady');
```

Additionally you have to enable the video player in the skills settings.